# What is the current avg hourly rate for a senior c# developer in the US?

Tags: c#

Odd question I know, but I am about to pay someone for offshore consulting services from the United States and trying to get a feel for what the hourly rate for a senior developer is. Will be using a few hours a few only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is $42 (kidding).

But in all seriousness, there is no answer to your question. The definition of 'senior' can vary and even for 2 people with the exact same experience and skill set different jobs might pay differently. If you are hiring a contractor to perform some work that might take a few hours why not offer a fixed rate for the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your question would be better asked [here](http://careeroverflow.com/) but heres a good place to start with your search. [Bereau of Labor](http://www.bls.gov/oes/current/oes151031.htm)

Comment: and yeah I know its the US but could potentially give you a comparable statistic. IE look up cost of living in country x where x is the persons country of origin and see if you could find something comparable in terms of cost of living in a particular state in the US.